# what are the real world use cases of docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers

I understand docker containers features like app isolation, Server Consolidation, ... but I am wondering what are the real world use cases for Containers. How are you using containers in Production environment? Are they being used to host web services and web sites? Can you please give me some examples?

Thanks

Comment: I respect your decision to put this on hold but I think this is valid topic to discuss on this platform.

Answer (score 5):

- First decoupling and distributing applications into microservices.

So I'll give you an example I work with where you have the old method of deploying an application lets say a rails application that's a monolith application, i.e with the db, web app, a background task scheduler like sidekiq(in the case of python RabbitMQ), and redis to hold temporal (key, value) data. All this services running on a single server would mean this application has a single point of failure at any given moment. If something were to fail means that your whole application is offline while you rush off to trace what failed. If you had taken your application split it into small pieces known as a micro-service where each part of your application is packed into a container with the libraries it needs then deployed independently and dynamically to form part your overall application. Decoupling your application into these manageable components and reducing the probability of your application ever failing entirely. Furthermore, decoupling allows container-based applications to be deployed easily and consistently, regardless of whether the target environment is a private data center, the public cloud, or even a developer’s personal laptop.

- Dev and Ops separation of concerns

Take the part where most people build a release during deployment and may sometimes fail during deployment. With a container you get to build your image before release time which and you can run an environment similar to the one in production with no guesswork and this makes it easy for you to roll out more frequently without concern of failure/ or rather reduced. it also increases the consistency to which release/build your application.

> Containerization provides a clean separation of concerns, as
>   developers focus on their application logic and dependencies, while IT
>   operations teams can focus on deployment and management without
>   bothering with application details such as specific software versions
>   and configurations specific to the app.

Just have a read on these two links and it should clear up some stuff on your end.

[Containers 101](https://cloud.google.com/containers/) google and this
[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)